# Web service written in both WCF and Java

Tags: c#, java, .net, wcf, web-services

Can I write a web service that implements the same methods and returns the same custom objects using both C#/WCF and also Java Web Services? And if so, can I then access the web services using a single web reference but with different addresses?

I'm asking because I have to host a web service that has a GetCitations and GetTerms method for publically exposing our database content. We are on IIS, so I was going to do it with WCF. However, other partners in the project also have to host an equivalent service and they are all Java based.

We are then building a software app that needs to connect to any number of these services (as defined at runtime by a user). I am expecting that we can have one set of classes to connect to these services (but with different endpoitn addresses), but am not sure whether I'm right in expecting this to work.

Is this possible? 
And what considerations/restrictions are there?

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, so your going to have 2 separate web services, performing the same actions, but completely separate implementations?

Comment: Yes, 2 or more. We have multiple organisations wanting to implement their own instance of a 'standard' web service for exposing their own database content in a common way.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a problem, if you make sure that both services have equivalent wsdl files and you use http/soap binding.

I am not sure about using the binary (net.tcp) one with WCF, though. It might be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use JAX-WS (Java 6) to expose a method as a web service.

The JAX-WS stack allows for automatically generating the correct WSDL at runtime.

The .NET team can then take that WSDL, and use standard tools to create a mock implementation of that WSDL.  This mock implementation is then used as the actual .NET implementation, and you then use standard tools to generate the WSDL for *that* web service.

You now have to web services with the same semantics each with their own WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Both Java and .NET can implement a SOAP compliant web service, so the answer is yes, you can write a .NET and a Java webservice that implement the same WSDL.

Comment: @fiver, @Thorbjørn. Thanks for the input. So it sounds possible from what you are all saying. Are there issues with returning lists or custom objects (e.g. List<Citation>) as the web service response?

Comment: @fiver, @Thorbjørn. If the WSDL is exactly the same, then I should be able to call the same method on either endpoint by using the one class generated by svcutil.exe - right?

Comment: @Steve - The WSDL defines the objects as XML; the actual objects inside the .NET and Java web services won't be identical (due to different implementations), but they will serialize to the same XML for the purposes of the web service.  So yes, you'll be able to call the two webservices using the same proxy (just changing the address)

Comment: thanks. That was what I thought. I've noticed that when I implemented a WCF service the WSDL for it includes my namespaces but also one pointing to http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/. Any tips on how to avoid that?

Comment: @Steve - That's a good question; I'd suggest asking as a separate question.